# How to set Html class with a javascript function?

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, razor

i display 4 buttons for each elements in a list.

i want to know which button has data inside so i create an ActionResult and this returns true if contains data.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TieneNotificacion(string Pnombre, string Pcorreo1, string Pprefijo)
{
var lista = agp.CC15_EscalaMandoPorUsuario(Pnombre,Pcorreo1,Pprefijo);
if(lista != null){
 return Json(true);
}
else{
return Json(false);
}
}
```

in the view i want to set the button class "btn btn-xs" if the method return false and "btn btn-xs btn-info" if return true.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function tieneNotificacion(Nombre,Correo1,Prefijo){
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: "/CentralSoluciones/TieneNotificacion",

            data: { Pnombre: Nombre, 
                Pcorreo1: Correo1,
                Pprefijo: Prefijo },

            success: function (data) {

                if (data) {
                    return "btn btn-xs btn-info"
                }
                else {
                    return "btn btn-xs"
                }

            }

        });
    }
});
```

and the html tag is like that:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Detalles", new { Pnombre= item.Nombre, Pcorreo1=item.Correo1, Pprefijo=list.Prefijo })"
                     class=tieneNotificacion(@item.Nombre,@item.Correo1,@list.Prefijo)>
                    <span>@list.Prefijo</span>
                </a>
```

Comment: define HTML class by a javascript function; the javascript function call an ActionResult by Ajax and define the type of class to set to the button

Comment: in other words i want to see the button color blue if the Url.Action returns a view with data and color gray if doesnt have data, sorry for my english

Comment: Would you post your button?

Comment: is the <a> tag not a button, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can set the class for your button within the AJAX call.

**Suppose you have these buttons**

```
  <input type="button"  />
  <input type="button"  />
  <input type="button"  />
```

**Update your javascript to**

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
            function tieneNotificacion(Nombre,Correo1,Prefijo){
                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",

                    url: "/CentralSoluciones/TieneNotificacion",

                    data: { Pnombre: Nombre, 
                        Pcorreo1: Correo1,
                        Pprefijo: Prefijo },

                    success: function (data) {

                        if (data) {

                            $( ":button" ).addClass("btn btn-xs btn-info");
                           //To set a class completely, instead of adding one or removing one. 
//    use this $( ":button" ).attr('class','btn btn-xs btn-info');
                        }
                        else {
                         $( ":button" ).addClass("btn btn-xs");
                          //To set a class completely, instead of adding one or removing one. 
//    use this $( ":button" ).attr('class','btn btn-xs');
                        }

                    }

                });
            }
        });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3b341dv7/)

Comment: i think do like that but each row has 3 buttons, and each button need to call the same javascript function with one distinct params

Comment: Then do not use an ID use a class selector. or use attribute selector

Comment: and how can i send the params to the function? each row has 3 buttons and each button call the function with two same params and one distinct